# Append differing number of characters to strings in list of strings

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of strings:

```
strs = ["aa", "bbb", "c", "dddd"]
```

I want to append spaces to the end of each string so that each string is 4 characters long. That is, I want the end product to look like this:

```
strs_final = ["aa  ", "bbb ", "c   ", "dddd"]
```

I think list comprehension is the way to go, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this. I know how to, for instance, pick out the strings that are of length 3 and add one space to them:

```
[i+" " for i in strs if len(i) == 3]
```

But I don't know how to add varying numbers of spaces for varying lengths of strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution is to use [str.ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)

```
[i.ljust(4) for i in strs]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). The general form for format specifier is:

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
```

so, if you provide the `width` it will be padded with space:

```
>>> list(map('{:4}'.format, strs))
['aa  ', 'bbb ', 'c   ', 'dddd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [i+" "*(4-len(i)) for i in strs]
['aa  ', 'bbb ', 'c   ', 'dddd']
```

The key point being `"x"*4` gives you `"xxxx"`